# Options for custom connecting a temperature sensor with a USB 2.0

Tags: usb, embedded, onewire

I'm exploring a little project that would involve creating a custom USB device by connecting a temperature sensor to a USB device. There seems to be a dearth of information online about how to do this. Originally I found a pretty good sensor that uses the 1-wire protocol, and someone outlined how they were able to connect this with USB in [this tutorial.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58958/Wire-USB-Interface) However, they still ended up having to use a proprietary library from 1-wire's manufacturer to read data from the sensor. Ideally, I would avoid this, and could write my own device driver in C if necessary.

I'm inexperienced with embedded and hardware, so just trying to explore options and find good resources for this project. Is something like this even possible without using a proprietary SDK?  What would be a good standard to work with (1-wire, I2C, etc.)?

Comment: I recommend a USB device-capable MCU so that you can use actual relevant USB classes such as HID instead of shoehorning it all into CDC or ACM.

Comment: As another option you could combine a chip such as the CH340  with a small non-USB MCU (easier if it has a UART or bit-bang the serial communications between the chips). You might even be able to share the 12MHz crystal.

Comment: Yet another approach would be to use a USB to I2C bridge.  [MCP2221A](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP2221A), for example.  This saves you the task of programming the microcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need a proprietary library for bitbanging onewire. The following code is from an application for AVR µCs [I did some years ago](http://vusb.wikidot.com/project:vusb). If you used another µC family, you may have to implement the special Onewire/iButton crc functions yourself.

You don't need much more to communicate with an onewire slave chip. The OwReadROM() function is the only one I needed for my application but you can easily write functions for triggering a temperature conversion and reading the result based on that.

For the USB part, either use V-USB as I did (USB1.1 low-speed only) or an  USB-enabled µC.

```c
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>     /* for _delay_ms() */
#include <util/crc16.h>     /* for _crc_ibutton_update() */

/*
 *  Onewire host functions.
 */
static inline void owClear(void) {
    DDRB  |= (1 << PB0);
    PORTB &= ~(1 << PB0);
}

static inline void owSet(void) {
    PORTB |= (1 << PB0);
    DDRB  &= ~(1 << PB0);
}

static inline uchar owGet(void) {
    return ((PINB & (1 << PB0)) == 0);
}


/* Onewire idle load function. */
void owIdleLoad(void) {
    /* Release OW line from master. */
    owSet();

    /* Wait 20ms to allow slaves load their power capacitor. */
    _delay_ms(20);
}


/* Onewire transfer reset */
uchar owReset(void) {
    uchar sample;

    /* Reset all slaves. */
    owClear();
    _delay_ms(0.7);

    /* Release OW line from master. */
    owSet();
    _delay_ms(0.04);

    /* Check presence pulse from slave(s). */
    sample = owGet();

    /* Wait until slaves release OW line, max. 240µs. */
    _delay_ms(0.24);

    /* Return whether some device was present on onewire. */
    return sample;
}


/* Read a single bit from onewire. */
static uchar owReadBit(void) {
    uchar sample;

    /* Send bit marker. */
    owClear();
    _delay_us(1);
    owSet();
    _delay_us(10);

    /* Check if a slave keeps pulled the OW line low. */
    sample = owGet();

    /* Wait until slaves release OW line, max. 120µs. */
    _delay_us(120);

    /* Return bit from slave. */
    return (sample?0:0x80);
}


/* Read a byte from onewire. */
uchar owReadByte(void) {
  uchar data;

    data=owReadBit();
    data>>=1;
    data|=owReadBit();
    data>>=1;
    data|=owReadBit();
    data>>=1;
    data|=owReadBit();
    data>>=1;
    data|=owReadBit();
    data>>=1;
    data|=owReadBit();
    data>>=1;
    data|=owReadBit();
    data>>=1;
    data|=owReadBit();

  return data;
}


/* Write a bit to onewire. */
static void owWriteBit(uchar bit) {
    /* Start bit marker. */
    owClear();
    _delay_us(1);

    /* If bit should be 1, immediately release OW line. */
    if (bit & 0x01) {
        /* Release OW line. */
        owSet();

        /* Wait 60µs. */
        _delay_us(60);
    } else {    
        /* Wait 60µs. */
        _delay_us(60);

        /* Release OW line. */
        owSet();
    }   
}


/* Write a byte to onewire. */
void owWriteByte(uchar data) {
    owWriteBit(data);
    data>>=1;
    owWriteBit(data);
    data>>=1;
    owWriteBit(data);
    data>>=1;
    owWriteBit(data);
    data>>=1;
    owWriteBit(data);
    data>>=1;
    owWriteBit(data);
    data>>=1;
    owWriteBit(data);
    data>>=1;
    owWriteBit(data);
}


/* Read ROM onewire command. */
uchar owReadROM(void) {
    uchar i, crc;

    /* Onewire reset. */
    if (owReset() == 0) {
        /* No slave present. Fail. */
        return 0;
    }

    /* Read ROM for DS2400 and DS2401. Other slaves will ignore this command. */
    //owWriteByte(0x0f);
    owWriteByte(0x33);

    /* Read 8 bytes answer from OW slave. */
    crc = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        iButtonBuffer[i] = owReadByte();
        crc = _crc_ibutton_update(crc,iButtonBuffer[i]);
    }

    /* Remember the iButton ID is valid. */
    iButtonBufferValid = (crc == 0);

    /* Success if crc is 0. */
    return iButtonBufferValid;
}
```

Comment: I take it it's almost necessary to use a USB-capable MCU? What does the process look like if you skip the MCU?

Comment: With v-usb, you don't need an USB-capable MCU, but can only do USB1.1, low-speed – but then, it's more than fast enough for sampling thousands of temperature sensors.

Comment: If you skip the MCU, you had to use a pre-built onewire host adapter as the DS9490R or the DS9097U (or wire up a DS9097U compatible one yourself), but you need a driver for your host OS then. For example, with Linux it would be either the kernel itself or OWFS which could act as a driver.